# Antlr4 failed semantic predicate should lead to picking another alternative

Tags: antlr4

I need to disable some alternative in big list of them, for some concrete context.
I decided to do this via semantic predicate, but faced strange behaviour. It looks like I'm doing smth wrong, but I can't understand why.

Below is a maximally simplified grammar, which should allow me to show whats going on;

Input text is `101` and I expect it to be parsed as `(rule1 1 0 1)`. Because of failed predicate I expect antlr to chose second alternative for `rule1`, which exactly match input sequence.

But Antlr throws an exception `line 1:1 no viable alternative at input '0'` and produce such parse tree: `(rule1 1 (rule2 0 1))`.

```
grammar Test;
rule1:
   '1' rule2
   | '1' '0' '1' // This branch should be checked, if predicate in rule2 fail and no viable alternative was found
;

rule2:
   {false}? '0' '1'
   | '1' '1' // this branch will not match
;
```

I have tried to catch exception and do smth with it, but I can understand how. I think I should somehow report parser, that this branch fails, and it should try next one.

Am I doing all wrong, or I just miss smth trivial?

P.S. Yes, it's a hack, and I'd better split my `rule2` alternatives and use in `rule1` only list of valid ones, but it will lead to problem's with alternative precedence and make direct left recursion - indirect in my actual grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantic predicates in an ANTLR 4 *parser* rule can have two effects:

1. The predicate could be evaluated as part of the prediction process, which determines the path taken through the grammar.
2. The predicate could be evaluated after a decision is made as part of verifying a correct path was taken (and throwing a `PredicateFailedException` if it returns false).

The first case is only used when a predicate appears on the left side of a decision. Since your grammar includes a `'1'` between the start of `rule1` and when it gets to the predicate in `rule2`, the predicate will not be evaluated as part of choosing between the first and second alternatives in `rule1` (it will be assumed to be true). You could refactor your grammar as follows to *fully* preserve the original parse tree while also enabling the predicate during prediction.

```
grammar Test;
rule1:
   '1' ( rule2
       | '0' '1' // This branch should be checked, if predicate in rule2 fail and no viable alternative was found
       )
;

rule2:
   {false}? '0' '1'
   | '1' '1' // this branch will not match
;
```

Comment: what if the rule2 is repeated in other rules? e.g. `rule1 : rule2 ("+" rule2)*`